# Borel measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm struggling on the following question from a past paper:
Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a Borel measurable function and let $h:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $h(x,y)=f(x-y)$. Prove that $h$ is Borel measurable.

I first approached this by trying to use that $k(x,y)=x-y$ is continuous and $f$ is measurable but I am not sure if this implies $f\circ k$ is Borel measurable (I know that it implies $k\circ f$ is Borel measurable). Could somebody provide me with a hint? 
N.B. The part before this question asked to show that for $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ Borel, we have $B\times \mathbb{R}$ is Borel in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
h=f\circ s,
$$
where $s(x,y)=x-y$. Thus
$$
h^{-1}(A)=s^{-1}\big(\,f^{-1}(A)\big)
$$
So if $A\in{\mathscr B}(\mathbb R)$, then $f^{-1}(A)\in{\mathscr B}(\mathbb R)$, since $f$ is Borel measurable.

Also, if $B\in{\mathscr B}(\mathbb R)$, then $s^{-1}(B)\in{\mathscr B}(\mathbb R^2)$, since $s$ is continuous, and hence Borel measurable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean $s(x,y)$? Also, why does $s$ being continuous imply $s^{-1}(B)$ is Borel? For $B$ open or closed I can see why this holds but what about for Borel sets that are neither open nor closed?

Comment: @Eduardo: Yes. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Any function $f: X \to Y$ is Borel measurable $\iff$  $f^{-1} (E) \in \mathscr{B}_X$ for every open set $E \subseteq Y$.  Why?   Because $V := \{E \subseteq Y : f^{-1}(E) \in \mathscr{B}_X\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains all open sets, so $\mathscr B_Y \subseteq V$.